# The different between with GCC inline assembly and VC

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I am migrate VC inline assembly code into GCC inline assembly code.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  // this is raw code.
  __asm
  {
    cmp cx, 0x2e
    mov dword ptr ds:[esi*4+0x57F0F0], edi
    jmp BW::BWFXN_RefundMin4ReturnAddress
  }
#else
  // this is my code.
  asm
  (
    "cmp $0x2e, %%cx\n\t"
    "movl %%edi, $ds:0x57F0F0(0, %%esi, 4)\n\t"
    "jmp %0"
    : /* no output */
    : "i"(BW::BWFXN_RefundGas3ReturnAddress)
    : "cx"
  );
#endif
```

But I got error

```
Error：junk `:0x57F0F0(0,%esi,4)' after expression
/var/.../cckr7pkp.s:3034: Error：operand type mismatch for `mov'
/var/.../cckr7pkp.s:3035: Error：operand type mismatch for `jmp'
```

Refer the Address operand syntax

`segment:displacement(base register, offset register, scalar multiplier)`

is equivalent to

`segment:[base register + displacement + offset register * scalar multiplier]`

in Intel syntax.

I don't know where is the issue.

Comment: What's supposed to be in `cx` and `edi` at that point in the MSVC version?  You're not doing anything to get gcc to put anything into those input registers.  (And BTW, you're not clobbering CX, you're using it as one of the 2 sources in a compare.)  It's not going to be as simple as just getting the syntax right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is highly unlikely to work just from getting the syntax correct, because you're depending on values in registers being set to something before the `asm` statement, and you aren't using any input operands to make that happen.  (And for some reason you need to set flags with `cmp` before jumping?)

If that fragment worked on its own somehow in MSVC, then your code depends on the choices made by MSVC's optimizer (as far as which C value is in which register), which seems insane.

Anyway, the first answer to any inline asm question is https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm if you can avoid it.  Now might be a good time to rewrite your thing in C (maybe with some `__builtin` functions if needed).

---

**You should use `asm volatile` and a `"memory"` clobber at the very least**.  The compiler assumes that execution continues after the `asm` statement, but at least this will make sure it stores everything to memory before the `asm`, i.e. it's a full memory barrier (against compile-time reordering).  But any destructors at the end of the function (or in the callers) won't run, and no stack cleanup will happen; there's really no way to make this safe.

You might be able to use `asm goto`, but that might only work for labels within the same function.

---

**As far as syntax goes**, leave out `%%ds:` because it's the default segment anyway.  (Everything after `$ds` was considered junk because `$ds` is the address of the symbol `ds`.  Register names start with `%`.)  Also, just leave out the `base` entirely, instead of using zero.  Use

```
"movl %%edi, 0x57F0F0( ,%%esi, 4)  \n\t"
```

You could have got a disassembler to tell you how to write that, by assembling the Intel version and disassembling in AT&T syntax.

You can probably implement that store in pure C easily enough, e.g. `int32_t *p = (int32_t *)0x57F0F0;` `p[foo]=bar;`.

---

**For the `jmp` operand**, [use `%c0` to get the address with no `$`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86-Operand-Modifiers) so the compiler's asm output is `jmp 0x12345` instead of `jmp $0x12345`.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for more links to guides + docs.

You can and should look at the `gcc -O2 -S` output to see what the compiler is feeding to the assembler.  i.e. how exactly it's filling in the asm template.

**I tested this [on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'void+ext(void)%3B%0Along+foo(int+a,+int+b)+%7B+return+0%3B+%7D%0Astatic+const+unsigned+my_addr+%3D+0x000045678%3B%0A%0A//__attribute__((noinline))%0Avoid+testasm(void)%0A%7B%0A%09asm+volatile(+//+and+still+not+safe+in+general%0A%09++++%22movl+%25%25edi,+0x57F0F0(+,%25%25esi,+4)+%5Cn%5Ct%22%0A%09%09%22jmp+++%25c%5Bfoo%5D+++++++%5Cn%5Ct%22%0A%09++++%22jmp+++foo+++++++++++%5Cn%5Ct%22%0A%09%09%22jmp+++0x12345+++++++%5Cn%5Ct%22%0A%09%09%22jmp+++%25c%5Baddr%5D++++++%22%0A%09:+//+no+outputs%0A%09:++//+%22S%22+(value_for_esi),+%22D%22+(value_for_edi)%0A%09%5Bfoo%5D+%22i%22+(foo),%0A%09%5Baddr%5D+%22i%22+(my_addr)%0A%09:+%22memory%22++//+prevents+stores+from+sinking+past+this%0A%09)%3B%0A%0A%09//+make+sure+gcc+doesn!'t+need+to+call+any+destructors+here%0A%09//+or+in+our+caller%0A%09//+because+jumping+away+will+mean+they+don!'t+run%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:30.752464973563256,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g62,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell+-fverbose-asm+-m32',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+6.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:32.04958124661338,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g62,filters:(b:'0',binary:'0',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell+-fverbose-asm+-m32',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+6.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),k:37.19795377982338,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) to make sure it compiles, and see the asm output + disassembly output**

```
void ext(void);
long foo(int a, int b) { return 0; }
static const unsigned my_addr = 0x000045678;

//__attribute__((noinline))
void testasm(void)
{
    asm volatile( // and still not safe in general
        "movl %%edi, 0x57F0F0( ,%%esi, 4) \n\t"
        "jmp   %c[foo]       \n\t"
        "jmp   foo           \n\t"
        "jmp   0x12345       \n\t"
        "jmp   %c[addr]      "
    : // no outputs
    :  // "S" (value_for_esi), "D" (value_for_edi)
    [foo] "i" (foo),
    [addr] "i" (my_addr)
    : "memory"  // prevents stores from sinking past this
    );

    // make sure gcc doesn't need to call any destructors here
    // or in our caller
    // because jumping away will mean they don't run
}
```

Notice that an `"i" (foo)` constraint and a `%c[operand]` (or `%c0`) will produce a `jmp foo` in the asm output, so you can emit a direct jmp by pretending you're using a function pointer.

This also works for absolute addresses.  x86 machine code can't encode a direct jump, but GAS asm syntax will let you write a jump target as an absolute numeric address.  The linker will fill in the right `rel32` offset to reach the absolute address from wherever the `jmp` ends up.

So your inline asm template just needs to produce `jmp 0x12345` as input to the assembler to get a direct jump.

asm output for `testasm`:

```
    movl %edi, 0x57F0F0( ,%esi, 4) 
    jmp   foo               #
    jmp   foo           
    jmp   0x12345        
    jmp   284280        # constant substituted by the compiler from a static const unsigned C variable
    ret
```

disassembly output:

```
 mov    %edi,0x57f0f0(,%esi,4)
 jmp    80483f0 <foo>
 jmp    80483f0 <foo>
 jmp    12345 <_init-0x8035f57>
 jmp    45678 <_init-0x8002c24>
 ret
```

Note that the jump targets decoded to absolute addresses in hex.  (Godbolt doesn't give easy access to copy/paste the raw machine code, but you can see it on mouseover of the left column.)

**This only works in position-dependent code (not PIC)**, otherwise absolute relocations aren't possible.  Note that many recent Linux distros ship gcc set to use `-pie` by default to enable ASLR for 64-bit executables, so **you may need [`-no-pie -fno-pie` to make this work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)**, or else ask for the address in a register (`r` constraint and `jmp *%[addr]`) to actually do an indirect jump to an absolute address instead of a relative jump.

Comment: I use `0x57f0f0(0, %%esi, 4)` instead of `$ds:0x57F0F0(0, %%esi, 4)` still junk error `found ',', expected: ')'   junk ,%esi,4)' after expression `

Comment: @guilin桂林: I thought the `0` might be ok there, but I guess not.  Updated.

Comment: Thanks. Address is OK now, but for the jmp section is still not work. the `BW::BWFXN_RefundGas3ReturnAddress` is actually just `static const u32 BWFXN_RefundGas3ReturnAddress = 0x0045D474;` in source.

Comment: The reason to use inline assembly here, is try to hook another program in runtime. Actually I use mingw-w64 to migrate it not GCC.  https://github.com/bwapi/bwapi/blob/master/bwapi/BWAPI/Source/Assembly.cpp#L127

Comment: `"jmp *%0" :  : "r"(BW::BWFXN_RefundGas3ReturnAddress)` compiled pass

Comment: @guilin桂林: `mingw` is a Windows port of gcc.  And yes, if your jump target is an absolute address, not a symbol name, you want a register-indirect jump like you're using.  In non-PIC code, there might be a way to get it encoded as a JMP REL32 which would be more efficient than an indirect jump.  Maybe with `.set my_symbol, %0` and `jmp my_symbol`, to keep the linker happy.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @guilin桂林: turns out you can use `%c0` to get a direct jmp to a compile-time constant absolute address.  The linker takes care of filling in the right rel32.  See my updated answer.